# Restore previously used database

Tags: c#, database, deployment

I have publish a windows form application including a database. The published application is running well both my and others computer. But the problem is i have saved many data in my database and now i need to change some option of my application. After completing the change if i install the new application my old data r gone here the database is empty. So how can i keep all my data after my new publish or how can i use my before used database.

I followed this tutorial to publish my application:[Deploy C# Project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqvgerKYtOg)

How can i solve this problem can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Couldn't you literally just copy the database on the client machine so you have a backup in case you do overwrite the database file with an empty database?

Comment: Sorry, that is not helping.It did not match with the new published app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy the stored database from your client computer which is located in 
`C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0` directory. and then replace this database with newly installed app data which will be in same directory